# Java, Spring Boot + Gradle Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have two similar projects. They have developed separetely but have similar code.
Now my first project is working well while second one has dependencies conflicts.

I see in External Libraries that they have different versions of packets. Moreover the project which run Gradle-6.5 version work fine, however that one which use Gradle-6.1 fail.

However, the projects have the same gradle settings and build files. I completely don't understand why the second one use Gradle-6.1. I have spend many hours investigating the issue, I have completely uninstalled IDE, but nothing helps.

How could I tell a project DO NOT RUN Gradle-6.1 as first project does?

Comment: could you please post some code/script details?

Comment: @HakanDilek The issue source that code is the same (!) in gradle settings, while one run 6.5 version and other 6.1. That's an issue!

Comment: Yeah, I have read that. Anyway, maybe you can help us help you with a code-snippet.

Comment: Try to build the project from the command line, using gradle or gradle wrapper. In this way you are sure that you are using the same gradle version.

Comment: @marc good idea. I will try now.